# NullPointer with tiled.tmx

Tags: android, andengine, tile

I have a tiled.tmx file i am loading into andengine. But i keep getting this nullpointer

```
10-31 21:15:08.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 21:15:08.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6508): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 21:15:08.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6508):     at com.fttech.test_ninja.Ninja_FightActivity.onLoadScene(Activity.java:117)
```

Here is where the nullpointer is pointing me, i dont know why.

```
try {
        final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(this, this.mEngine
                        .getTextureManager(), // TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA,
                        TextureOptions.NEAREST);
        this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset(this, "tmx/TileMao.tmx");
} catch (final TMXLoadException tmxle) {
        Debug.e(tmxle);
}


tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);
SceneMainScene.attachChild(tmxLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `mEngine` is not `null` and `mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers()` does not return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to add enough debug code to determine what's failing to return a valid reference for you, or just step through the code with the debugger in Eclipse. My guess would be that the loadFromAsset call is failing so mTMXTiledMap is NULL and your call on getTMXLayers fails. If that's the case you'll need to see why that call is failing to find your tmx file.